# Importing CSV file to Oracle when only DML are allowed

Tags: sql, database, oracle, csv, import

My database is hosted on a server to which I can only issue [DML statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language).

Is there an SQL command (for Oracle) that I could use to  fill a table with the entries from a CSV file? The columns of the CSV file and the table are the same, but if there is a version of the command where I could decide which field from the file goes to which column it would be even better.

Also, I cannot install anything besides the Oracle SQL Developer so what I need is an SQL code that I can run from there. I believe that SQL*Loader and external tables don't help in this situation.

Comment: This has been answered many times in SO.  Please do a search next time.

Comment: you could use external tables

Comment: @OldProgrammer I saw the solution with the external tables, but I was more hoping to get something similar to LOAD DATA INFILE command. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/load-data.html

Comment: @Ivan _" I was more hoping to get something similar to LOAD DATA INFILE command"_ You definitively need to explain what _key feature_ of `LOAD DATA INFILE`  you are looking for? Maybe you have some very specific needs not addresses by _external tables_?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I don't have the access to the server so external tables are hard to use. I'd like to use SQL*loader command LOAD DATA INFILE (to load from a file to a table) and, if possible, call it within the Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I edited the post. I think this is a different problem than the one that the others had.

Comment: @Ivan _"I think this is a different problem"_ I've update your question to put emphasis on the fact that only _DML statements_ are allowed. Please review that change. However, notice that something was unclear to me in the original text: if you can only issue DML statements, you cannot _create table_. On the other hand, if you have  [`CREATE ANY TABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables013.htm#ADMIN11708) privilege, you should be able to create _external tables_.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux The problem is that the database is stored on a server and that besides the connection to the database I can't access the server and cannot, therefore, run the `sqlldr` command. On the other hand, as far as I've understood, if I want to create an external table from a file, the file must be stored locally on the same server, which I again can't do. Am I wrong about any of this? Or are my problems now clearer?

Answer (score 1):

**use oracle external table**

```
create directory ext_data_files as 'C:\'; -- create oracle directory object point to the directory where your file resides, using this we will fetch the csv data

create table teachers_ext (
      first_name     varchar2(15),
      last_name      varchar2(15),
      phone_number   varchar2(12)
)
organization external (
  type oracle_loader
  default directory ext_data_files
  access parameters (fields terminated by ',' )
  location ('teacher.csv')
)
reject limit unlimited
/
```

**your csv will be like**

John,Smith,8737493

Foo, Bar, 829823832

Answer (score 0):

Directly copied from [Oracle 9i documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch11.htm#1007030):

> ```
> CREATE TYPE student_type AS object (
> student_no CHAR(5),
> name CHAR(20))
> /
>
> CREATE TABLE roster (
>   student student_type,
>   grade CHAR(2));
> ```
>
> Also assume there is an external table defined as follows:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE roster_data (
>   student_no CHAR(5),
>   name CHAR(20),
>   grade CHAR(2))
>   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir
>                          ACCESS PARAMETERS (FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',')
>                          LOCATION ('foo.dat'));
> ```
>
> To load table roster from roster_data, you would specify something
>   similar to the following:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO roster (student, grade)
>   (SELECT student_type(student_no, name), grade FROM roster_data);
> ```

The *external table access driver* (aka `ORACLE_LOADER`) accept a bunch of options to handle many different cases: fixed width, CSV, endianness (binary data), separators... Once again, see [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10825/et_params.htm) for the details.

---

> ... if there is a version of the command where I could decide which field from the file goes to which column it would be even better.

As you understood it now, *external tables* are handled like any other table. So, you can as usual re-order and/or perform calculation on the fly in your `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement.